# Calling assembly function from c leads to segmentation fault

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64

This is my assembly program add.s

```
.globl add

add:
   movl 4(%esp), %eax
   movl 8(%esp), %ebx
   addl %ebx, %eax
   ret
```

This is my C program. I am trying to call the assembly program from the C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b);

int main() {
   int res = add(5,6);
   printf("%d",res);
   return 0;
}
```

But the above code gives me a segmentation fault. What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you create the same function in C, how does the compiler generate code for it? Does it do some stack setup that you miss? Does it save the registers it use to not clobber them (maybe they are used elsewhere)?

Comment: This is tagged with `x86-64`. If that is true, this is not how arguments are passed on that architecture in any ABI I'm aware of. What is the actual operating system and architecture this is compiled on? How is it compiled and linked? (crashing probably happens because reading from (%esp) is bad because it's supposed to be %rsp).

Comment: I have to concur with Art. Are you compiling this as 32 or 64-bit code?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the *cdecl* calling convention, you are using the `ebx` register which is supposed not to be *clobbered*: its value has to be saved and then restored by the callee if it is going to be modified.

The *caller* assumes that `ebx` is not going to change by calling a function. Therefore if the *callee* modifies `ebx` it has to save it first and then restore it to its original value before returning from the function.

---

The registers `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` can be used without having to save them first and then restored. Therefore, I would recommend replacing `ebx` with `edx` in your code:

```
add:
   movl 4(%esp), %eax
   movl 8(%esp), %edx
   addl %edx, %eax
   ret
```

Comment: I thought `ebx` is a general register (read it here http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~amza/www.mindsec.com/files/x86regs.html), why it is not supposed to be overwritten?

Comment: @CIsForCookies it can be overwritten, but the caller assumes the register `ebx` does not change by calling a function, for that reason the callee must first save it and then restore it before returning back.

Comment: oh... ok. What about `push ebx` at the start of `add`? will it be ok? (obviously using `edx` instead is the right way, but just trying to understand)

Comment: @CIsForCookies doing `push ebx` and then `pop ebx` before returning will also do

Comment: This is ABI-dependent, it depends on the OS.

Comment: Another question - if `add` was inlined with no function call, would using `ebx` still be a problem?

Comment: @CIsForCookies I would say that if the compiler is aware of the fact that `ebx` is being clobbered, then it wouldn't be any problem. But this doesn't seems to be possible here, since the `add` function is in another translation unit.

Comment: @CIsForCookies may be inline assembly specifying `ebx` as a clobbered register?